# Change screen in kivy from multiple\ buttons

Tags: python, kivy

so im new to kivy and im building a app but one part of it has me stumped, what i have so far it will go through a text file and create buttons based on the number of lines in a loop and i want all of these buttons to go to the same screen. here is my code its a mix of different YouTube guides but none of them have the answer

python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.text import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
import os

from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout

cwd = os.getcwd()

class LoginWindow(Screen):
    pass
class Stack(StackLayout):
    screen = StringProperty('LoginWindow')
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        f = open(f'{cwd}/items/items.txt', 'r')
        lines = f.readlines()
        for i in lines:
            barcode = i.replace('\n','')
            b1 = Button(
                text=str(barcode),
                size_hint=(1, None),
                size=(200, dp(50)),
            )

            b1.bind(on_press=self.button1)
            self.add_widget(b1)



    def button1(self, instance):
        id = ((instance.text).replace('\n', ''))
        f = open(f'{cwd}/items/{id}.txt', 'r')
        lines = f.readlines()
        print(instance.text)
        print(f'''Item Name: {lines[0]}\nPrice: {lines[1]}\n''')


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass
class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):

        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(LoginWindow(name='LoginWindow'))
        sm.add_widget(ScreenOne(name='ScreenOne'))
        sm.add_widget(ScreenTwo(name='ScreenTwo'))
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

.kv file:

```
LoginWindow:

<LoginWindow>:
    Stack:
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If you just want to change `Screen`, add `App.get_running_app().root.current = 'ScreenOne'` to the `button1()` method.

Comment: john, i love you